# Why I am getting NoExplicitTypeError?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

I am createing `Nest.js` application and I decided to create my project with GrapQL. I read some documentation and I decided to go **code first** approach(GraphQL schema should automagically render itself). For this approach it was needed to install **type-graphql** which is really cool, but after I created some simple examples with only primary types I decided to do something more challanging.

In my appliaction I have `BlogEntity`(from those **Entities** type-graphql is generating GraphQL schema) which is using `ArticleEntity` becouse it is needed to add typing to `posts`, `projects` and `tutorials`. I created my resolver and defined `@ResolveProperty` for `posts`, `projects` and `tutorials`. When I am trying to run `nest start` command i am getting this error:

> throw new errors_1.NoExplicitTypeError(prototype.constructor.name, propertyKey, parameterIndex);
>
> > NoExplicitTypeError: You need to provide explicit type for BlogEntity#posts !

Can someone explain me why I am getting this error and what should I do to fix it?

**BlogEntity**

```js
import { Entity, Column, ObjectIdColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import { ArticleEntity } from '../../articles/models/article.entity';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class BlogEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  posts: ArticleEntity[];

  @Field()
  @Column()
  projects: ArticleEntity[];

  @Field()
  @Column()
  tutorials: ArticleEntity[];
}
```

**BlogResolver**

```js
@Resolver(() => BlogEntity)
export class BlogResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly blogService: BlogService,
    private readonly articlesService: ArticlesService) {}

  @Query(() => String)
  async helloBlog(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello blog';
  }

  @ResolveProperty('posts', () => ArticleEntity)
  async getPosts(): Promise<ArticleEntity[]> {
    return await this.articlesService.findAll();
  }

  @ResolveProperty('projects', () => ArticleEntity)
  async getProjects(): Promise<ArticleEntity[]> {
    return await this.articlesService.findAll();
  }

  @ResolveProperty('tutorials', () => ArticleEntity)
  async getTutorials(): Promise<ArticleEntity[]> {
    return await this.articlesService.findAll();
  }

}
```

If you need anything else ping me in the comment section

Comment: Why do you have `@ResolverProperty` everywhere when there are no `@Query()` or `@Mutation()` decorators that relate to the `BlogEntity`?

Comment: I think I do not undertand your question, but i added ```@ResolverProperty``` because without this I was also getting this error but i found this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/226) with soullution so I decided to try this but it didn't worked

Comment: As of now, there is no way for you to run graphql requests to get a `BlogPost` because there is no `@Query()` that relates to the `BlogEntity`. `@ResolverProperty()` is used for define how to resolve _properties_ of the originally queried object.

Comment: I understand, I added it only for kind of test (i was getting this error and i thought that maybe by adding this i can resolve my problem). SO how should I get rid of this error (i thought it was because i have this unresolved custom types in my BlogEntity) ?

Comment: I believe you should add in some sort of `@Query()` method that resolves to a `BlogEntity`, similar to how your `helloBlog` resovles to a String

Comment: ye but what kind of ```@Qury()``` ? for example ```@Query(() => [ArticleEntity])
  async getPosts(): Promise<ArticleEntity[]> {
    return [];
  }```. It is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202290/discussion-between-kanow-and-jay-mcdoniel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So problem was not in `@ResolverProperty` and my resolver. Problem of this error was in deffinition of BlogEntity fields: `posts`, `projects` and `tutorials`. You can ask why? So for every type which is not primary (expect number there you also have to define what it will be Float or maybe Integer) and also for every field which is an **array** even array of primary types like string you also have to define a type of returnig values. How to do it, you just need to add `returnTpyFunction` to `@Field()` decorator.

**Example**

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class BlogEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: string;

  @Field(() => [ArticleEntity])
  @Column()
  posts: ArticleEntity[];

  @Field(() => [ArticleEntity])
  @Column()
  projects: ArticleEntity[];

  @Field(() => [ArticleEntity])
  @Column()
  tutorials: ArticleEntity[];
}
```